# script to get users image from their login name

Tags: javascript, image

I'm looking for the answer to a question.. that seems really complex.

I'm looking to get a file name from a user that logs in.
For example:

User logs in as 'admin' and the file that comes is /admin.jpg
User logs in as 'john' and the file that comes is /john.jpg

I currently have the script to get the users name, the script is:

```
<?php echo ''. get_current_user(); ?>
```

Hope someone can help.. I have looked all over

Jason

Comment: We cannot see the script. Please edit it.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do, it's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the name is `get_current_user()` then the image is

```
$image = "/" . get_current_user() . ".jpg"
```

You just need to include this in a `img` tag...

```
echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Image" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the images in a folder (named user_images for example) and than you can take the image of every user like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo 'user_images/'. get_current_user().'\.jpg'; ?>">
```